# What is meant by background playing of youtube videos?

Tags: android, cordova

My Phonegap android app got rejected by play store for violating device and Network abuse policy. I have a page in my app that has a youtube player embedded, but the videos can be played only when the play button is clicked. Video pauses when the app goes to background (assuming clicking on home button takes the app to background state). Here the "background playing" refers to "playing video when the app is in background" or "any video that is embedded in the app using html iframe tag" ? There are few similar questions but nothing helped. How to debug and solve this issue?

**Here is the original message :**

> Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Device and
>   Network Abuse policy. Before submitting your app for another review,
>   read through the policy and modify your app to make sure it doesn't
>   enable background play of YouTube videos. If you submitted an update,
>   the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

Comment: I think you are trying to keep running YouTube videos in background, or overlay of other view that likely the reason for this warning

Comment: I too thought the same but no video is playing when the app is in background. Video stops when the view is changed or the app is in background.

Comment: Can you post an example of your code (the stuff pertaining to the YouTube player) so that we can better determine the cause of your app being rejected?

Comment: Youtube player part of the code is just an html iframe something like this : <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/xyz" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Can anyone answer this please ?